# Line numbers in Visual studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How to see line numbers in Visual studio IDE ??

I know we can see the Line numbers in status bar and i Know we can go to perticular line by pressing ctrl+G but i want to see the line numbers.

I have tried to find them in View menu bu not able to.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > (highlight a language or do All Languages) Then there's a checkbox under Display on the right side of the window. Just click OK after that and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

Tools->Options

Under the "Text Editor" category you can enable and disable lines numbers for individual (or all) languages.

Comment: i will upvote the answer since i can accept only one answer